# meta content device-width effecting the image it make the image inside the column not clear

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, responsive-design, viewport

After adding this line on my website to make the navbar responsive  It made the images inside the column not clear in the phone screen. Check the two pictures to understand more what I mean!
[image: this is with the viewport] [image: this is without]
When I remove the name="viewport" from the meta the photo look clear.

How can I fix this? I need the photos to be clear and I need to add this name="viewport"  so my website will be responsive!

Here is my code

```
<meta  content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>


.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #555555;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 8px 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #fcfdfc;
}

.topnav a.active {
  color: #00405d;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .logo img {
    width: 100px;
}

}
</style>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-54517731358aab10" async="async"></script>
  <div class="header-top">
    <div class="wrap"> 
      <p><%= image_tag "2.png" %> FREE SHIPPING on orders over CAD $150</p>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <div class="header-bottom">
    <div class="wrap">
    <div class="header-bottom-left">
      <div class="logo">
        <%= link_to root_path do %><%= image_tag "twinkledreamslogo.png" %><% end %>
      </div>
      
      
  <%= link_to "Home",root_path, class: "active" %>
  <%= link_to "Shop",teethers_path %>
  <%= link_to "Baby", baby_path %>
  <%= link_to "reviews", reviews_path %>      
  <%= link_to "Contact",new_contact_path,class: "color7"%>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>
 
    
     <div class="header-bottom-right">
         <div class="search"> 
         <%= form_for "",url: teethers_path, role: "search", method: :get  ,class: "textbox" do %>
         <%= text_field_tag :search, @search_term,value: "Search", onfocus: "this.value = '';" ,onblur: "if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search';}" %>
              <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" id="submit" name="submit">
        <% end %>  
        
   
        <div id="response"> </div>
     </div>
   </div>
    </div>
     <div class="clear"></div>
     </div>
  </div>  </div>

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
  </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner fwslider">

    <div class="item active">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 col-lg-3">
          <%= image_tag "mirabel.jpg",style: "height: 400px;"%>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 col-lg-3">
          <%= image_tag "icecream.jpg",alt: "icecream baby custom teether",style: "height: 400px;"%>
          
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 col-lg-3">
          <%= image_tag "giancarlo1.jpg",style: "height: 400px;"%>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 col-lg-3">
          <%= image_tag "elephant.png",alt: "elephant baby custom teether",style: "height: 400px;"%>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 col-lg-3">
          <%= image_tag "robbie.jpg",style: "height: 400px;"%>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 col-lg-3">
          <%= image_tag "elephant2.jpg",alt: "elephant baby custom teether",style: "height: 400px;"%>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 col-lg-3">
          <%= image_tag "isa.jpg",style: "height: 400px;"%>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 col-lg-3">
          <%= image_tag "oreo.jpg",alt: "oreo baby custom teether",style: "height: 400px;"%>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: code on codepen for more details

Comment: Question is not clear. What do you mean by "Photo looks clear/unclear" ?
Add some images for visual analysis or codepen link.

Comment: @AnandBait I edit my question with pictures